# libyahoo Segmentation fault

Tags: c, linux, yahoo

I wrote this code:

```
#include <libyahoo2/yahoo2.h>
#include <libyahoo2/yahoo2_callbacks.h>


int main() {
    int id ;
    char username[255] = "slam";
    char password[255] = "ss" ;
    id = yahoo_init(username, password);
    enum yahoo_status mYahoo ;
    mYahoo = YAHOO_STATUS_AVAILABLE ;
    yahoo_login(id , mYahoo );


    return 0;
}
```

Compile it, `gcc -l yahoo2 y.c -o yahoo` and run it with `./yahoo` gives me a error: `Segmentation fault`

```
(gdb) run

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x001379b1 in yahoo_login (id=1, initial=0) at libyahoo2.c:1735
```

line 1735 code is:

```
tag = YAHOO_CALLBACK(ext_yahoo_connect_async) (yd->client_id,
        host, yss->pager_port, yahoo_connected, ccd, 0);
```

and see this :

```
(gdb) list YAHOO_CALLBACK
Function "YAHOO_CALLBACK" not defined.
```

How do I debug this?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I debug this?

Execute these commands:

```
(gdb) print yd->client_id
(gdb) print yss->pager_port
```

My guess would be that one or both of the above commands will fail, because `yd` or `yss` is NULL.

If so, the problem is *earlier* in libyahoo2.c, and it (apparently) doesn't check for errors properly.

The reason you can't `list YAHOO_CALLBACK` is most likely that it is a macro. Look in `libyahoo2/yahoo2_callbacks.h` -- it's very likely to be defined there.

Also, your link command line:

```
gcc -l yahoo2 y.c -o yahoo
```

is totally bogus. Correct command line should be:

```
gcc y.c -o yahoo -lyahoo2
```

You may want to read [this explanation](http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html) to understand why order of sources and libraries on command line matters.