# Segmentation fault error in compile yahoo2 header

Tags: segmentation-fault

```
#include <libyahoo2/yahoo2.h>
#include <libyahoo2/yahoo2_callbacks.h>
#include <yahoo2.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int id ;
    char username[255] = "slam";
    char password[255] = "ss" ;
    id = yahoo_init(username, password);
    enum yahoo_status mYahoo ;
    mYahoo = YAHOO_STATUS_AVAILABLE ;
    yahoo_login(id , mYahoo );

    return 0;
}
```

hi all  when i compile this code the out put is Segmentation fault
any body can help me to solve it plz

Comment: segmentation fault where? It should tell you where the problem occured...

Comment: i do not know. the error is this        Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: possible duplicate of [libyahoo Segmentation fault](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9203461/libyahoo-segmentation-fault)

Answer (score 0):

> the error is this Segmentation fault (core dumped)

You need to learn how to diagnose problems like this.

Since you are on a UNIX system of some sort (you'll do well to *specify* what system you are using in the future), the tool for such diagnosis is called a debugger.

On Linux and many other OSes, the debugger is called `gdb`.

So you run

```
gdb /path/to/your/executable
(gdb) run
# GDB will stop at crash point
(gdb) where   # <<== this command will tell you where your crash is happening
```

Once you know where the program crashes, you'll be able to ask better question.

Answer (score 0):

tnx for helping

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xb7fac9b1 in yahoo_login (id=1, initial=0) at libyahoo2.c:1735
1735    libyahoo2.c: No such file or directory.
    in libyahoo2.c

(gdb) where

## 0  0xb7fac9b1 in yahoo_login (id=1, initial=0) at libyahoo2.c:1735

## 1  0x080486a0 in main () at b.c:20

(gdb)